# Failed to start asp.net core 2.1 webapi

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi

Just deploy to IIS server my .NET Core 2.1 webapi. Got error `502.5 HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure` from the URL `http://localhost/api`. Open the Event Viewer, it is `IIS AspNetCore Module` eror.

```
Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/DEFAULT WEB SITE/API' with physical root 'C:\apps\api\' failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet .\Webapi.dll', ErrorCode = '0x8007010b : 0.
```

Remote to the server and run `dotnet .\Webapi.dll` successfully.

Any idea please

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Run the report and paste the info as part of question.

Comment: Have you installed the right version of dotnet web hosting package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error code 0x8007010b means IIS could not find dotnet.exe but i havr all dotnetcore frameworks installed. Finally the issue is the windows previdge. The default account for iis pool doesnt have enough power to access the folder c:\dotnet... It is resolved by running more powerful account.